# Error al instalar jquery

Tags: jquery, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy usando la terminal de visual studio code para instalar jquery en mi proyecto pero cuando lo quiero instalar me sale ese error y el paquete que sale ahí ya lo borre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error dice que, el proyecto no tiene `package.json` y este es necesario para las operaciones de npm.

Primero, revisa que estés en el ruta correcta donde esta el `package.json`.

En caso de no tenerlo, lo que debes hacer es `npm init`, seguir los pasos y posterior hacer `npm install jquery`

Comment: Muchas Gracias si me sirvio

Comment: @LuisUribe Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Recuerda aceptar la pregunta como de ayuda y / o votar +1.